AWS cli could not connect to API endpoint
I have encountered the following issue running the AWS cli on an EC2 instance. When I try to interact with cloudwatch logs in eu-west-1 a connection error is displayed.
$ aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 describe-instances | jq ".Reservations|length > 0"
true
$ aws ec2 --region eu-west-2 describe-instances | jq ".Reservations|length > 0"
false
$ aws ec2 --region eu-west-3 describe-instances | jq ".Reservations|length > 0"
true
$ aws logs --region eu-west-1 describe-log-groups | jq ".logGroups|length > 0"

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
$ aws logs --region eu-west-2 describe-log-groups | jq ".logGroups|length > 0"
false
$ aws logs --region eu-west-3 describe-log-groups | jq ".logGroups|length > 0"
false

The IAM user for the CLI has the required permissions. In fact, to determine if there was an IAM issue I then granted the user the AdministratorAccess policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Even with this policy applied the same error occurs when attempting to interact with eu-west-1. Is this an AWS issue or is there a configuration issue at play?
The EC2 instance in question is also in eu-west-1. However, I then launched an instance in eu-west-3 and using the same IAM credentials for aws I was able to run describe-log-groups for the three eu-west regions without any errors:
$ aws logs --region eu-west-1 describe-log-groups | jq ".logGroups|length > 0"
true
$ aws logs --region eu-west-2 describe-log-groups | jq ".logGroups|length > 0"
false
$ aws logs --region eu-west-3 describe-log-groups | jq ".logGroups|length > 0"
false

